# (Long) Removing Single Quotes From Strings in a List

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x, csv

This is all a bit vague because the program is rather in-depth, but stick with me as I will try to explain it as best I can. I wrote a program that takes a `.csv` file and turns it into `INSERT INTO` statements for a MySQL database. For example:

```
ID   Number   Letter   Decimal   Random
0    1        a        1.8       A9B34
1    4        b        2.4       C8J91
2    7        c        3.7       L9O77
```

would result in an insert statement like:

`INSERT INTO table_name ('ID' int, 'Number' int, 'Letter' varchar(). 'Decimal', float(), 'Random' varchar()) VALUES ('0', '1', 'a', '1.8', 'A9B34');`

However not all of the `.csv` files have the same column headers yet they need to be inserted into the same table. For files that do not have certain column headers I would like to insert a `NULL` value to show this. For example:

Lets say the first `.csv` file, **A**, has the information:

```
ID   Number   Decimal   Random
0    1        1.8       A9B34
1    4        2.4       C8J91
```

The second `.csv` file, **B**, has different column headers:

```
ID   Number   Letter   Decimal
0    3        x        5.6
1    8        y        4.8
```

After being converted to an `INSERT` statement and put in the database it would ideally look like this:

```
ID   TableID   Number   Decimal   Letter   Random
0    A         1        1.8       NULL     A9B34
1    A         4        2.4       NULL     C8J91
2    B         3        5.6       x        NULL
3    B         8        4.8       y        NULL
```

**Now this is where I will probably start to lose you.**

In order to accomplish what I needed I first take each file and create a master list of the *all* the column headers that the `.csv` files:

```
def createMaster(path):
    global master
    master = []
    for file in os.listdir(path):
        if file.endswith('.csv'):
            with open(path + file) as inFile:
                csvFile = csv.reader(inFile)
                col = next(csvFile) # gets the first line of the file, aka the column headers
                master.extend(col) # adds the column headers from each file to the master list
                masterTemp = OrderedDict.fromkeys(master) # gets rid of duplicates while maintaining order
                masterFinal = list(masterTemp.keys()) # turns from OrderedDict to list
    return masterFinal
```

Which would take all the column headers from multiple `.csv` files and assemble them into a master list in order without duplicates:

`['ID', 'Number', 'Decimal', 'Letter', 'Random']`

This provides me with the first part of the `INSERT` statement. Now I need to add the `VALUES` part to the statement, so I take and make a list of all the values in each row of each `.csv` file one at a time. For each row a temporary list is created, and then the list of column headers for that file is compared to the master list of column headers for all files. It then goes through each thing in the master list and tries to get the index of that same item in the column list. If it finds the item in the column list it inserts the item from the row list at that same index into the temporary list. If it can't find the item it inserts `'NULL'` into the temporary list instead. Once it has finished the temporary list it then turns the list into a string in the proper MySQL syntax and appends it to a `.sql` file for insertion. Here is the same idea in code:

```
def createInsert(inPath, outPath):
    for file in os.listdir(inpath):
        if file.endswith('.csv'):
            with open(inPath + file) as inFile:
                with open(outPath + 'table_name' + '.sql', 'a') as outFile:
                    csvFile = csv.reader(inFile)
                    col = next(csvFile) # gets the first row of column headers
                    for row in csvFile:
                        tempMaster = [] # creates a tempMaster list
                        insert = 'INSERT INTO ' + 'table_name' + ' (' + ','.join(master)+ ') VALUES ' # SQL syntax crap
                        for x in master:
                            try:
                                i = col.index(x) # looks for the value in the column list
                                r = row[i] # gets the row value at the same index as the found column
                                tempMaster.append(r) # appends the row value to a temporary list
                            except ValueError:
                                tempMaster.append('NULL') # if the value is not found in the column list it just appends the string to the row master list
                            values = map((lambda x: "'" + x.strip() + "'"), tempMaster) # converts tempMaster from a list to a string
                            printOut = insert + ' (' + ','.join(values) + '):')
                            outFile.write(printOut + '\n') # writes the insert statement to the file
```

**Finally now time for the question.**

The problem with this program is that `createInsert()` takes all the row values from the tempMaster list and joins them with `'` marks via the line:

```
values = map((lambda x: "'" + x.strip() + "'"), tempMaster)
```

This is all fine and dandy *except* that MySQL wants `NULL` values to be inserted and just `NULL` instead of `'NULL'`.

**How can I take the assembled row list and search for `'NULL'` strings and change them into just `NULL`?**

*I have two different ideas:*

I could do something along these lines pull the `NULL` string from the `'` marks and replace it in the list.

```
def findBetween(s, first, last):
    try:
        start = s.index(first) + len(first)
        end = s.index(last, start)
        return s[start:end]
    except ValueError:
        print('ERROR: findBetween function failure.')

def removeNull(aList):
    tempList = []
    for x in aList:
        if x == 'NULL':
            norm = findBetween(x, "'", "'")
            tempList.append(norm)
        else:
            tempList.append(x)
    return tempList
```

Or I could maybe add the `NULL` values into the list without `'` to begin with. *This is within the `createInsert()` function.*

```
for x in tempMaster:
    if x == 'NULL':
        value = x
        tempMaster.append(value)
    else:
        value = "'" + x + "'"
        tempMaster.append(value)
values = map((lambda x: x.strip()), tempMaster)
printOut = insert + ' (' + ','.join(values) + ');')
outFile.write(printOut + '\n')
```

However I think neither of these are viable because they would slow the program down significantly (with the larger files these raise a `MemoryError`). Therefore I am asking your opinion. I apologize if this was confusing or hard to follow. Please let me know what I could fix to make it easier to understand if this is the case and congratulations for making it to the end!

Comment: Have you actually tried them to see how slow they are?

Comment: Yes I have. It can run some of the smaller `.csv` files but generates a `MemoryError` when performing on some of the larger ones.

Comment: Tell me, what would happen to your DB if this was in one of the columns: `" DROP TABLE table_name;"`? This method of inserting data leaves you vulnerable to SQL injection attack. You should never add arbitrary input to SQL queries. You should look into using something like SQLAlchemy to help insulate you.

Comment: @IanAuld This is definitely the next step if I decide to implement this program further. However for now this is just acting as a temporary method to insert old data, which I know is safe, into a newer database. I will look into your comment as well as SQLAlchemy to help avoid these potential problems in the future. Thanks for the advice!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

instead of

```
values = map((lambda x: "'" + x.strip() + "'"), tempMaster)
```

put this

```
 values = map((lambda x: "'" + x.strip() + "'" if x!='NULL' else x), tempMaster)
```

#### Edit

Thanks for accepting/upvoting my simple trick but I'm not sure this is optimal.
On a more global scope, you could have avoided this map/lambda stuff (unless I'm missing something).

```
                for row in csvFile:
                    values = [] # creates the final list
                    insert = 'INSERT INTO ' + 'table_name' + ' (' + ','.join(master)+ ') VALUES ' # SQL syntax crap
                    for x in master:
                        try:
                            i = col.index(x) # looks for the value in the column list
                            r = row[i] # gets the row value at the same index as the found column
                            value.append("'"+r.strip()+"'") # appends the row value to the final list
                        except ValueError:
                            value.append('NULL') # if the value is not found in the column list it just appends the string to the row master list
```

Then you have `value` properly populated, saves memory & CPU.

Comment: I had made an error in part of the program not featured in the question but once I fixed it this worked perfectly. Thanks!

Comment: Check my last edit, maybe we can do even better & simpler (ok we won't use `map` or `lambda` and that does not look as impressive, that's the downside :))

Answer (score 0):

I checked your requirement i found that you have multiple CSV in your directory. These csv have dynamic column. My approach is create a static list of all columns

`staticColumnList = ["ID","TableID","Number","Decimal","Letter","Random"]`

Now when reading your file take header row and make a temp list for tuples for corresponding columns like

`[(ID, column no in csv), (TableID, 'A' - File Name), (Number, column no in csv) etc...]`

If you don't have column in csv then put x in correspondence like `("Letter", x)`. Now with each row make a loop and assign or pick values like this:-

```
wholeDataList = []
rowList = []
for column in staticColumnList:
    if int of type(column[1]):
      rowList.append("'"+str(rowCSV[column[1]])+"'")
    elif 'X' == column[1]:
      rowList.append('null')
    else:
      rowList.append("'"+column[1]+"'")


wholeDataList.append("("+",".join(rowList)+")")
```

At last you have well prepared statements, like this:-

```
qry = "INSERT into .. ("+",".join(staticColumnList)+") values " + ",".join(wholeDataList)
```